# I need to get the path of a file input in an html table row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web site where there is  a slideshow of product pictures. In my js code for the website management menu, I list the current slideshow images in rows of an html table. I want the user to be able to change a picture in a row by selecting from the html file selector for that row. If the user makes a selection, I want to capture the selected file's path and update the mysql table with it. I know that for security reasons browsers normally don't allow this but there should be a way to do it. However, I have tried many of the suggestions on the Internet about this but none worked. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<tbody>
      <% if(data.length){ for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>
        <tr> 
          <td><%=data[i].prod_id%></td>
          <td><img src="<%=data[i].slshow_img_file%>" id="slshow_img"/></td>
          <td><button style="display:block;width:160px; height:21px;" class="chg_file_btn" onclick="document.getElementById('img_file').click()"></button></td>
          <td><input type="file" class="img_file" name="img_file" id="img_file" accept='image/*' onchange="get_filename()"></td>
          <td><button type="submit" class="chg_img_btn" id="chg_img_btn" onclick="add_slshow_img()">Change the picture</button></td>
          <td><button class="del_img_btn" >Remove this product from the list</button></td>
        </tr> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_filename(event) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    const new_filename = files[0].name;
    alert(new_filename);
}
```

Comment: None worked because it is not allowed. What if you could get it and load it? Like `file:///c:/bitcoins/wallet.dat`

Comment: "I know that for security reasons browsers normally don't allow this but there should be a way to do it.", this is strange. There "should" is a bit entitled, no? There isn't. Unless the user drags a file explicitely into the browser, at which point you can read it's data, you _cannot access a users personal files_.

Comment: in terms of mere javascript, the reason why your `event` is undefined (and thus also `event.target` throws an error) is because you are using an inline event handler and you need to explicitely call the function passing the event `onchange="get_filename(event);"` for that code to make it work. But the whole scenario where you need to then update the database with such information will require a further request to an api

Comment: I have also tried fileReader API but it didn't work.

Comment: it's really not clear what you are aiming to achieve. You said _If the user makes a selection, I want to capture the selected file's path_ what do you mean by selection? the code instead suggested you had an `input type=file` with the change event wired. The user is expected to pick a file from its local filesystem through that or not?

Comment: You can not get the path of the file. You will get something with 'fakePath'

Comment: Diego D, you are right, just adding the 'event' parameter to the onchange line worked.  I din't think it would be this simple. This question can now be closed.

Comment: so I see that lots of people insisting on you cannot read the path was the wrong lead.

Answer (score -1):

For specifying correct path inside img tag. Remember two points through which you can specify correct path of the file.

**Point 1:** If you want to specify for file which is above your present directory, we write "../". Using this you can go above in your directory.

**Point 2:** If you want to specify for file which is inside your present directory, we write "/". Using this you can go inside in your directory.

Comment: Hey dude, "remembering two points" isn't really an answer. I understand you can't comment yet, but prove yourself by getting 50 reputation first, which you won't by giving what essentially amounts to a comment as an asnwer.